# error: cannot access ListViewCompat class file for android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat not found

Tags: android, android-appcompat

*i have this error when updated appcompat to 23.1.1 :*

Error:(264, 51) error: cannot access **ListViewCompat**
class file for **android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat** not found

- appcompat : 23.1.1
- target 23
- compile 23
- sdk 24.3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it was moved out of the internal package `android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat`.

It is now found in `android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat`.

Update your java files to

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat;
```

and your layout files accordingly

```
<android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: i will check this in another time , i change my code to avoid use this class , by the way probably your advise looks true .

Answer (score 7):

With the new compileSdkVersion 27 seems that `android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat` doens't exist anymore. Now you should use `android.widget.ListView`

Comment: None of the other anwswers worked for me, had to change to android.widget.ListView.